# How to change the font-style and color or action sheet in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I have a action sheet 'selectedActionSheet'. I created a `alertcontroller` with `actionsheet`

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [selectedActionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];
```

Now, I change the tint color as follows:

```
if ([alertController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
{
   alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:99.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

This changes the color of the tint but when I click on the action sheet, Again i see the default blue color. Can somebody help me resolving this? I am new to Objective c.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `alertController` `tintColor` after the `presentViewController` i.e.

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:99.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

this will change default as well as highlighted color. Hope this will solved your problem.

If you simply want to present actionSheet, then please try below code-

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Hello Dear" message:@"I'm an actionSheet!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                                   //add code to make something happen once tapped
                                               }];

[alertController addAction: ok];

UIAlertAction *Cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                               //add code to make something happen once tapped
                                           }];

[alertController addAction: Cancel];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:99.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

actionSheet will look like this-

[image]

Comment: [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];    throws an exception. Can you suggest where to paste this lie of code?

Comment: where you are presenting your alertController. I think after this UIAlertController *alertController = [selectedActionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];

Comment: or show some more code, so that i can easily identify where to add this line according your code..

Comment: SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_alertController");
   if ([selectedActionSheet respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        alertController = [selectedActionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];
        if ([alertController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
       {
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:99.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
           
        }
    }
    
    [selectedActionSheet showInView:[self.tabBarController view]];

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you want using actionSheet means when you want to present alertController..

Comment: can you please edit your question with your full code for creating actionsheet and controller.. do not add code in comment, put it in question..

Comment: and also add the exception which you getting..?

Comment: @RiosK How you change the OK title color? Tint color changed the whole button title's of action sheet. How can I change single button tittle color?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

`UIActionSheet` actually uses `UIAlertController` in iOS 8, and it has a private property `_alertController`.

```c
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_alertController");
if ([actionSheet respondsToSelector:selector])
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [actionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];
    if ([alertController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
    {
        alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
```

To change all buttons colour

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah I understand. Well, it changes the color but when i click on that action i see a blue color(default  color). How do i change that?

Answer (score 0):

For font to set to alert view controller below is code...

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Your Alert Title" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
NSMutableAttributedString *hogan = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your alert description..."];
[hogan addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(24, 11)];
[alertVC setValue:hogan forKey:@"attributedTitle"];
```

For UIAlertController tint color...

```
alertVC.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:99.0/255.0 blue:265.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```